# iOS Bonjour NetServiceBrowser didRemove called at the wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour

I have a bonjour service which implements the NetserviceBrowser delegates on iOS in swift.

```
func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser,
                       didFind service: NetService,
                       moreComing: Bool) {if !moreComing {'update ui"}}

func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser,
                       didRemove service: NetService,
                       moreComing: Bool){if !moreComing {'update ui"}}
```

The service is finding and resolving services ok,  however I seem to get some strange behaviour with respect to removing services..

I have the following scenario:

1. Appliance comes online. - didFind service is called ok and service is resolved.
2. Appliance goes offline. - didRemove is **NOT** called.  no delegates are called.
3. Appliance comes back online - didRemove is called,  then didFind is called and the service is resolved again.

The browser service is running continually and has not been stopped.

Expected behaviour would be:

When the appliance goes offline then didRemove should be called.

I would also not expect to receive didRemove when the appliance comes back online ?

Can anyone advise whats why I do not receive the didRemove call when appliance goes offline (2) and why its being called when it comes back online (3).

Comment: Does `dns-sd -B <type>` on the macOS command line show the same behavior?

Comment: Could you find the answer for this?